# Is it possible to modify a pubsub message attribute?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

Is it possible to modify the attribute of a pubsub message before nacking it? I have a scenario where I would like to change the attribute of a message that cannot be processed further and hence has to be eventually nacked. Is that possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not possible to modify the attributes of a message after it is published, no. The closest thing you could do is publish a new message with the changed attribute and ack the original message.